# Make x-axis readable in the plot produced

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot, the music genre the people listen to on `x axis` and its count on `y axis`. The plot that is produced, is not clear at all.

I wrote the following call to draw the graph:

```
ggplot(csv, aes(x=music_genre)) + geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat = "count")
```

and the plot produced looks like:

[image]

As you could see, it is impossible to identify what is on the x-axis. How could I make it readable?

Is there a better way I can approach this?

Comment: It looks as though there are just too many genres for everything to fit on the x-axis, even if you wrap the strings. One possible workaround: add `+ coord_flip()` to your ggplot code to switch x- & y-axis. Another workaround if you're focusing on the more popular genres: group genres with small counts together into 'others' before plotting.

Comment: @Z.Lin Grouping to others would make sense. Could you show how to do this with an answer

Comment: @SuhailGupta can you put example of your data? using `dput` for example (`dput(csv)`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to rotate x-axis labels to be vertical and to use a smaller font size.

```
require(tidyverse)

csv <- read_csv("./ac1_survey.csv")
ggplot(csv, aes(x=`What genre of music do you like to listen to?`)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat="count") + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5),
        text=element_text(size=5))
```

Comment: Could you explain what does `stat="count"` exactly mean? I used this, but do not understand its meaning

Comment: From the `stat_count` doc: it counts the number of cases at each x position.

Answer (score 2):

Flip your axes with `coord_flip`.

Here's the problematic plot:

```
genres <- paste0('music_genre_', c(letters, LETTERS))

csv <- data.frame(music_genre = sample(genres, 500, replace = T))

ggplot(csv, aes(x=music_genre)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat = "count")
```

[image]
When the axes are flipped:

```
ggplot(csv, aes(x=music_genre)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat = "count") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Edit:
If you don't want to flip the axes, then use `forcats::fct_lump` to combine the smaller levels.

```
csv$music_genre <- forcats::fct_lump(csv$music_genre, n = 6)

ggplot(csv, aes(x=music_genre)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat = "count")
```

[image]

Comment: I would not want to flip the axis. Is there a way, I can group the genres with low count to others?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Might be worth looking at http://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

Answer (score 2):

In this situation I usually just rotate the tick labels with `theme`:

```
ggplot(csv, aes(x=music_genre)) + geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen", stat = "count") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
```

In ggplot2, `axis.text` in `theme` refers to the tick labels. The default angle is 0, and the text is rotated counterclockwise if you supply another number. `hjust` changes the justification of the text on the line (which is now rotated). For long text labels `hjust = 1` seems to work the best.

Comment: Good one. I was working on similar solution. I think `angle` should used as `90` to provide more room.